# On app release update - are the images kept or renewed?

Tags: ios, image, binary, release

When submitting a binary update, if I've replaced some images will they automatically be rolled out?  Or does the app on release keep the old images?  Assuming of course, that I've cleaned the app, and refreshed the build prior to compile.  I'm guessing it probably does reset the files...  But wanted to hear from someone else??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old images are removed and replaced by the new ones. Don't forget to update the version of the app in the project setting's:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When Apps are updated the download the entire app all over again. So any changes you make to your submission to the App store will propagate to all users who update.

The Only thing you have to make sure of is to remove the image from the Project or at least the build target.